# how to make a h2 background image 'dynamic' in height as well

Tags: css, image

I have a 1px wide by 35px high image, that I set as background for my `h2` elements. The accompanying CSS is as follows:

```
h2 {
    background:transparent url(./images/h1_bg.gif) repeat-x left top;
    font-size:18px;
}
```

As a result, the background is set as the image no matter what the length of the heading is, as long as the heading fits in one line. If the heading spills over to next line, then
image is not set as background for the wider area, as it repeats only in x direction. I think I need to create another image, example 1px wide by 60px high image and set it as background of the two-line heading. But I need some way to check if the heading is a two-line heading or not, so I can change the image background. How do I do that? Plus, is there some other way to accomplish this task?

Comment: Can you post an example of the background? It's hard to know what to recommend without it. You might be able to get away with a tall images positioned at `left bottom`.

Comment: the background is actually grey in color. the only difference from setting "background-color: gray " is that it is darker at top, and fades till it is white at bottom. but the bottom-most pixel of the image is again dark gray, so that the overall effect is of a graded-background with an underline, so to speak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using height.

```
  if($j("h1").height() > 30)
    {
        $j("h1").css("background","transparent url(./images/h1_bg_0.gif) repeat-x left top")
    }
  else
    {
        $j("h1").css("background","transparent url(./images/h1_bg_1.gif) repeat-x left top")
    }
```

Comment: You actually want to depend on javascript for something than can easilly be solved with static markup/css?!

Answer (score 3):

You usually deal with this by just creating a very tall image, like 100 pixels or more. Hold the bottom row colour for the remainder of the height.

Comment: Or, if the bottom of the image is a solid colour all the way across, you can set a background colour to match and leave the image as-is

Comment: True. ALthough if you have trasparent rounds or other cutouts you can't use background-color.

Comment: U62 -"What do you mean by "Hold the bottom row color for the remainder of the height?"

Comment: I mean if you have for example a 30px tall image with a gradient from top to bottom, load it up into your favourite image editing app, extend the height to 100px (or whatever) and then colour the new pixels in the same colour as the bottom row of the original image. An easy way to do this in most apps is to rectangle select the bottom row of pixles, copy and then paste and then stretch the bottom of the selection to the bottom of the image.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I thought it had something to do with css/html.  Thanks.